# Mailcow Reverse Proxy using Traefik not routing to the correct Nginx Service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, traefik, traefik-ingress

I am trying to follow the [community documentation](https://mailcow.github.io/mailcow-dockerized-docs/firststeps-rp/) on mailcow dockerized and I am using Traefik as my load balancer.

I have successfully obtained a SSL certificate and the `certdump` is working as expected when I check the logs.

The issue I have having is that the `nginx-mailcow` container is not receiving the requests when I visit `mail.example.com`. My Traefik logs show this:

> `level=error msg="entryPoint \"secure\" doesn't exist" routerName=moo@docker entryPointName=secure`
> `level=error msg="no valid entryPoint for this router" routerName=moo@docker`

My `docker-compose.override.yml` looks like this (not much different to the community documentation):

```yaml
version: '2.1' 
  services:
    nginx-mailcow:
      networks:
        traefik:
        web:
      labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.moo.rule=Host(`${MAILCOW_HOSTNAME}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.moo.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.moo.tls.certresolver=godaddy
      - traefik.http.routers.moo.middlewares=redirect@file
      - traefik.http.routers.moo.service=nginx-mailcow
      - traefik.http.services.moo.loadBalancer.passHostHeader=true
      - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-Proto=https
      - traefik.http.routers.moo.middlewares=https-redirect
      - traefik.http.services.moo.loadbalancer.server.port=80
      - traefik.http.routers.moo.entrypoints=secure
      - traefik.docker.network=web
  certdumper:
    image: humenius/traefik-certs-dumper
    container_name: traefik_certdumper
    network_mode: none
    volumes:
    - acme:/traefik:ro
    - ./data/assets/ssl/:/output:rw
    environment:
    - DOMAIN=${MAILCOW_HOSTNAME}    
networks:
  traefik:
    external: true
  web:
    external: true
volumes:
  acme:
    name: "traefik_acme"
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

I have also tried with only:

```yaml
labels:
- traefik.enable=true
- traefik.http.routers.moo.rule=Host(`${MAILCOW_HOSTNAME}`)
- traefik.http.routers.moo.tls=true
- traefik.http.routers.moo.tls.certresolver=godaddy
- traefik.http.services.moo.loadbalancer.server.port=80
- traefik.http.routers.moo.entrypoints=secure
- traefik.docker.network=web
```

This still did not work.

Comment: Please include the configuration of the traefik container, particularly the entrypoints.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a name for a service, you must use the same name in your service configuration, like this:

- traefik.http.routers.moo.service=**nginx-mailcow**
- traefik.http.services.<del>moo</del>**nginx-mailcow**.loadBalancer.passHostHeader=true

The `loadBalancer.servers` (notice the s in servers) doesn't have a `port` key, only `url`:

- <del>traefik.http.services.moo.loadbalancer.server.port=80</del>
- traefik.http.services.**nginx-mailcow**.loadbalancer.servers.url=['http://nginx-mailcow:80']

But as you are using defaults, you can omit all of the above =)

One more thing, I don't know how your Traefik container is configured but if your Traefik is running with a defined `traefik` network (internal) and a `web` network (public), you should use the `traefik` network in your Mailcow container as you want to route all external traffic through Traefik.

- <del>traefik.docker.network=web</del>

```
labels:
  - traefik.enable=true
  - traefik.http.routers.moo.rule=Host(`${MAILCOW_HOSTNAME}`)
  - traefik.http.routers.moo.tls=true
  - traefik.http.routers.moo.tls.certresolver=godaddy
  - traefik.http.routers.moo.middlewares=redirect@file
  - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
  - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-Proto=https
  - traefik.http.routers.moo.middlewares=https-redirect
  - traefik.http.routers.moo.entrypoints=secure
  - traefik.docker.network=traefik
```

#30daysofstackoverflow